# Pandas - Group by field and use column showing amounts of that field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I didn't know how to describe the situation correctly, I have this dataframe, I need to group it by date and have the column "status" show the quantities by date. How can I do it correctly?

```
Date        Time        N   Status          Kind
23/8/2020   00:00:00    aaa Completed       az
23/8/2020   00:00:01    bbb with warnings   az
23/8/2020   00:00:02    ccc aborted         ad
23/8/2020   00:00:03    rrr with warnings   az
24/8/2020   00:00:04    aze Completed       ad
24/8/2020   00:00:05    ggg Completed       ad
24/8/2020   00:00:06    ddd with warnings   az
21/8/2020   00:00:07    ww  Completed       az
21/8/2020   00:00:08    xxx aborted         az
21/8/2020   00:00:09    gge Completed       az
```

I need it to display as follows:

```
Date        Completed   with warnings   aborted
21/8/2020   2           0               1
23/8/2020   1           2               1
24/8/2020   2           1               0
```

I have tried grouping in different ways, also with ".to_frame". I'm not sure how to use ".agg ()"

Comment: pd.corsstab(df.Date, df.Status)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? _I'm not sure how to use ".agg ()"_ Then you probably need the Pandas documentation, not SO, right? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: [pandas how to use agg](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+how+to+use+agg+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk013YLCjNHOXi0xeM8wCRdrK9gYN_Q:1598393872241&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA5tyXsbfrAhXM3J4KHe4dAm8QrQIoBHoECBQQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @BEN_YO with that I solved the problem, it really was not necessary at all .agg()

> pd.corsstab (df.Date, df.Status) -  BEN_YO

Solution

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.Date, df.Status)
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```